# is there a way to get the header of an angular 4 index call from inside the app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building an Angular 4 application that is going to be imported into a WebSphere Portal Server as an script portlet. Once the script portlet is deployed, it is going to be accessed from a portal as a link in a dashboard. What I want to achieve, is to get the UID from the header inside my angular 4 app, then call the back end service and show the index page with all the info based on the UID provided in the header. Could this be possible? I am new in the angular world.

Comment: How are you going to load this ng 4 app? Is it an iframe or a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u click on that link I guess you will call some backend service. If no then make sure that this link will be related to one component and make sure that you call a backend service on init of this component which returns uid in header. Then you can access you headers like this

```
this.http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
   .map((res:Response) => { 
       console.log(res.headers); //your header which contains your uid
       return res.json();
   } )

let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(Object.assign({
      method: method,//Get or post
      url: environment.apiHost + url,
      body: body,
    }));
```